Ceiling wall tore off chunk
I had attached adhesive hooks to the ceiling, and upon removing them (in spite of being careful, the hooks had been up for years) tore off some of the wall.

I believe this is plaster wall and not drywall, but am open to being corrected on my understanding as well.
If anyone has any advice on how best to go about repairing this, would greatly appreciate. Thanks so much!

Or this: What is the best method to patch a large hole (2-3 inches) in drywall?

Drywall or plaster, the repair process is the same.
1- Remove any loose particles.
2- Check that the surrounding area is still firmly attached to the subsurface. If not remove any parts that are loose.
3-lightly sand the area to knock down any sharp edges.
4-  Brush or vacuum the dust off.
5- Apply a coat of drywall compound to fill the void. All purpose is good. If you want to work quick you can use some "hot mud" that dries quick.
6- When dry, lightly sand again and wipe the dust off.
7- Apply another skim coat covering a wider area.
8- When dry sand lightly any high spots or ridges. Then wipe with a damp sponge.
9- (Your ceiling looks like it has a light orange-peel texture.)  Spray the area with texture spray set on light to med-light. Spray in a spiral motion about 24 to 30 inches away from the surface to blend. Spray at least 6 inches outside the repair area. ( use plastic to cover a wide area on walls and the floor. Also practice on scrap cardboard or plastic, the initial spray from a new can is a large splurt. Don't spray that on the wall or ceiling.)
10- Allow to dry thoroughly. Then paint.
